# Indention issue in Python IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

IDLE config is set as

```
indentation width - 4 spaces
key set - IDLE classic windows
at startup - Open shell window
paragraph reformat width (in characters) - 70
```

I open up python IDLE and I am in the shell window.
I click file > new file.
I am now in the text editor.
I write a line of code. It doesnt matter what the syntax is.
When i push the "enter" button on my keyboard.
Instead of dropping down to the next line and being in the proper spot.
The little thing that blinks to show you where your at on the page is near the middle of the page...

```
number = float(input('what is your number? ')
               name = input('what is your name? ')


name = input('what is your name?')
               this is where it indents to
               it doesnt matter the syntax

number = int(input('what is your number?')
               if number > 5
               print (""" I am only using the enter key to
go to the next line""")
               else:
               print('this is what it does')
```

even if double spaced, should it not look like this?

```
number = int(input('what is your number?')
    if number < 5555
        print (' helloe')
    else:
        print('..............')
```

Comment: I think we need some more information here. Are you typing in the shell window, or the file edit window? Does it happen even in a brand new shell/file window, or only after you've typed some other code (which might have an `IndentationError` that's confusing IDLE, or even some perfectly valid code that's confusing IDLE even though it wouldn't confuse the parser)?

Comment: I am typing in the file edit window. If a open a new one and press enter it will stay on the left hand side and indent correctly. when ever i write a line of code. doesnt matter what it is even something simple like name = input('....') when i press enter i am indentied to somewhere in the middle. it is deff way more 4 spaces its like 7 tab spaces if that makes sense.

Comment: This sounds like an editor-spoecific (and not a python-related) issue to me.

Comment: @pyStarter: True, but IDLE comes with Python. So, if this were a weird "feature" of IDLE, I think it would be appropriate… but I don't think it is, I think it's a configuration issue.

Comment: @user3314737: Please edit that information into your question, so people trying to answer or learn from your question don't have to go trawling through comments to understand what you're asking.

Comment: @user3314737: Also, to clarify: You launch IDLE, you go to `File` | `New File` in the menu, you type `name = input("...")` and hit Enter, having done absolutely nothing else, and the cursor ends up a few characters from the left instead of at the left?

Comment: The reason I ask for this level of detail is that if you entered something like `name = input("...')` or `name = input("..."]` on a line, the next line would be a continuation of the same expression, so it would be perfectly correct for IDLE to start you off indented to the right of the `(`.

Comment: I clicked the python IDLE icon on my desk top. It starts up in the shell window. I click file > New file. I start typing a line of code. It does not matter what syntax I use. when I push the enter button, to jump to the next line. Instead of being at the far left of the page, or the correct indention point per the previous syntax. It is in the middle of the page. So then i push the backspace button roughly 8 times to make the starting point of that line when i type the first letter of the word where it needs to be....

Comment: It is not in the right spot because if i run check module, i get an indentation error

Comment: OK, if you really are typing a valid complete line for the first line (just to make sure, run Check Module _before_ typing anything on the second line… does it succeed?), then something is horribly broken in your configuration. Without knowing your platform, Python version, Tcl/Tk version, etc., config files, etc., there's no way anyone can debug that for you here. If you post all that info, someone _might_ be able to.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that you have your parenthesis matched. In your example you are missing one ')' at the first line.

```
number = float(input('what is your number? ') ) # this last parenthesis is missing in your example
name = input('what is your name? ')
```

The code would probably not run. You should make it a habit of always writing the closing parenthesis directly when you start an expression. In that way you know you've got them matched.

The reason why you get strange indentation is because without the closing parenthesis the editor thinks that the next line is part of the previous expression, which is your

```
number = float(input('what is your number? ')
               # notice how the indentation is right below
               # the opening parenthesis
               )
name = input('what is your name? '
             # notice how this indentation has a
             # a different position
             )
```

Comment: It’s really surprising that nobody else noticed that before you…

Comment: it is suggested in the comments, but not in a clear way. Also the edit history of the question shows that the actual code example was added late.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake on:

```
               if number > 5
```

Correct is:

```
               if number > 5:
```

and you wrote:

```
               name = input('what is your name? ')
```

but you should write:

```
name = input('what is your name? ')
```

without all that spaces.

Comment: You are correct that it is an error, but it is not the root cause of the problem. The root cause is a missing ')' character, see my answer.