# How can I stop IDLE from auto indeting?

Tags: python-idle, python-3.5, auto-indent

I've been coding in IDLE for a few days now. I have version 3.5.1 of python if that helps.

I was coding today and I noticed that when ever I start a new line it will be indented. It's quite annoying actually because most of the time I don't even need the code to be further indented and when I do it never puts the correct amount of space. It tends to be a tab and a space to far.

Is there any known method to prevent this?

Comment: "It tends to be a tab and a space to far" - a tab *and* a space? That's bizarre. Make sure your existing code doesn't have any mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: Try running your program to see if / where the SyntaxError is, I'm guessing you have an open bracket somewhere that isn't closed and IDLE is aligning the new lines with the open bracket.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indention issue in Python IDLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805255/indention-issue-in-python-idle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not way to turn auto indent off.  The Shell currently uses tabs because of the '>>> ' prompt (I hope to improve this someday).  The editor uses spaces according to the configuration setting on the Options / Configure IDLE /  Fonts/Tab tab.  The default is now 4 spaces per tab.  The smart indent is usually right according to PEP 8.  'Wrong indents' are usually a sign of a syntax error.  IDLE indents according to what you write, not what you intend.